# How do I bind a DataTable with complex data objects to a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datatable

My DataTable is programatically generated, and contains objects of type JobInstance in the cells.

`DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();`

```
// first column - label
dataTable.Columns.Add("JobType", typeof(string));

// other columns (data-driven)
foreach(string config in Configurations)
{
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn(config, typeof(JobInstance)); // !!!
    dataTable.Columns.Add(col);
}

// rows
foreach(string jobType in JobTypes)
{
    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
    row["JobType"] = jobType;

    foreach(string config in Configurations)
    {
        row[config] = GetJobInstance(jobType, config); // returns a JobInstance object
    }

    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);    
}
```

When I bind this DataTable to an ASP GridView, it only displays the first column. But if I remove the "typeof(Job)" when creating the column (the line with // !!!), the GridView displays all the columns by showing the result of JobInstance.ToString() in the cells. However, I have no access to the underlying JobInstance object, only the string values that are being displayed.

I need access to the JobInstance object when displaying the GridView (for example in the OnRowDataBound), because I want to access the fields inside JobInstance for each cell to determine formatting options, and add other links in each cell.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is possible.

Define a new Class for your `JobInstance` and put your fields in it, and for the sake of clarity let it be in a separate file.

in your aspx code-behind, define a `List<JobInstance>` collection, then fill it in the instances of `JobInstance`, then assign this list to the `DataSource` of your `GridView'.

To be able to access the instances of `List<JobInstance>`, make the list be a field-member in your aspx page's class.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Well I didn't want to display the fields of JobInstance as the columns. My columns are defined independently, and each cell is a JobInstance. But in the end I did something similar to what you suggested and access the objects in my data structure structure directly given the row/column, since there seemed to be no way to actually bind the objects to the gridview the way I want.